# ElasticSearch Replica shards Calculation

Tags: elasticsearch

We are using AWS managed Elasticsearch instance

Version : 6.2.3
Source data :  6 GB

We followed this document for calculating the primary shards and assuming replica shards = 1

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/sizing-domains.html#aes-bp-storage

Acc to this document primary shards = (Source Data + Room to Grow) * (1 + Indexing Overhead) / Desired Shard Size

primary shards = (6 + 24 ) * (1 + 0.1) / 30 = 30 * 1.1 / 30
Hence primary shards ~ 1 primary Shard

My questions are:

1] Can we use only 1 primary shard and 1 replica shard on production ES cluster
2] What is the thumb rule to calculate number of replica shards.
3] What is the ideal amount of data each primary shards should hold.
   As per AWS documentation 30 GB per Primary shard is fine, however on web people have recommended to use 10GB per primary shard.

Thanks in advance !!